# Creating new Cocoapod `Unable to find a specification` on pod install

Tags: cocoapods

I've gone through the Cocoapod guide for making a new pod.

The repo exists here: https://github.com/kkendall33/QuickInstantiating.

The `QuickInstantiation` pod spec looks like this:

[image]

But when I go to a different project and add `QuickInstantiating` to the Podfile:

[image]

and run `pod install`. I get this:

[image]

I just tested `pod install` with a different pod and it worked fine. This leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong with mine.

Answer (score 1):

The pod must be pushed before it can be referred to by version. For testing, you can use the same path syntax -

> pod 'QuickInstantiating', :path => 'relative/path'

like you used at https://github.com/kkendall33/QuickInstantiating/blob/master/Example/Podfile#L4

Otherwise you can push the pod to a private Specs repo if you do want to test the git repo before pushing the pod to trunk. Instructions at https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.